# Attachments disappearing from sent mail

Tags: gmail, 7.0-nougat, attachments

I'm having an issue with sending attachments from Gmail on android.
Whenever I send an attachment, it disappears from the message and is not delivered.
Visiting Gmail through web interface confirms the attachment is not there.
This happened to me using both my phone and tablet both running android 7.0

Comment: What *kind* of attachment was it  i.e., what format and what size?

Comment: I tried a .docx file and a pdf, both less than 1Mb

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling may help?

Comment: I installed Inbox by Gmail and did a few tests. No problems for now.